# Bat. file that open multiple url windows with firefox

Tags: batch-file

How to write bat file that open more than one URL in new windows in firefox? In chrome -new-window command works but what is the command in firefox?

Comment: yes i tried start firefox.exe -new-window URL already it doesn't work in firefox it only works for chrome

Answer (score 3):

Give a try for this sample :

```
@echo off
Set URL="www.google.com www.stackoverflow.com www.yahoo.com www.facebook.com www.twitter.com"
set NewTab=-new-tab
set NewWindow=-new-window
For %%a in (%URL%) Do (Start /d "%programfiles%\Mozilla Firefox" Firefox.exe %Newtab% "%%a")
For %%b in (%URL%) Do (Start /d "%programfiles%\Mozilla Firefox" Firefox.exe %NewWindow% "%%b")
```

Comment: If 64-bit Windows with 32-bit Firefox, you have to use `%programfiles(x86)%`.  Might want to add an `if exist "%programfiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox"` check in your script.

Answer (score 1):

As I know you can just list multiple URLs, separated by spaces. Firefox will open them as tabs in a new window.